# IIS Web configuration issue

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have an issue with my web.config file issue, can you please assist on this, present using the IIS 10 and windows server 2016

What type of changes need to done to this config file?

I have validated this files with the other environment files and verified the all Feature delegation settings all looks fine, still the issue is not resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

I had the same problem. Don't remember where I found it on the web, but here is what I did:

- Click "Start button"
- in the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
- in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
- Click: "World Wide Web Services"
- Click: "Application Development Features"
- Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI.

btw, I'm using Windows 7. Many comments over the years have certified this works all the way up to Windows 10 and Server 2019, as well.

**Solution 2:**

Follow the below steps to unlock the handlers at the parent level:

1. In the connections tree(in IIS), go to your server node and then to your website.
2. For the website, in the right window you will see configuration editor under Management.
3. Double click on the configuration editor.
4. In the window that opens, on top you will find a drop down for sections. Choose "system.webServer/handlers" from the drop down.
5. On the right side, there is another drop down. Choose "ApplicationHost.Config "
6. On the right most pane, you will find "Unlock Section" under "Section" heading. Click on that.
7. Once the handlers at the applicationHost is unlocked, your website should run fine.

Comment: This is the webform project or MVC. also you have published folder uploaded in IIS or direct full project folder?

Comment: @NareshYadala Also make sure that "ASP.NET 4.8" is checked.

Comment: This will not work,still finding the soluction for this issue

Comment: Hi Andrew ,how to check the ASP.Net 4.8

Comment: @NareshYadala It's one of the items in the "Application Development Features" section mentioned in this answer. I have found it gets unchecked with updates on Windows 10 sometimes.

Comment: @NareshYadala Oh, and make sure the website is using a .NET CLR Version 4.0 application pool.